# How can I use gtk.Builder.connect_signals to only connect signals from one window?

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk, glade

I'm developing a GUI application using Glade and Python 3. I've designed the UI in Glade; it consists of a main application window and a custom dialog with certain information that is shown when the user clicks a specified button. The dialog has its own class, let's call it `InfoDialog`; its constructor handles creating the dialog window and showing it. The class also has methods that correspond to signals sent by widgets in the dialog; for example, there is a "Cancel" button, and the signal (and the handler method in the class) is called `on_cancelButton_clicked`.

The problem is that I would like to connect this signal on a per-instance basis in `InfoDialog`'s constructor and specify `self` as user-data, so that `InfoDialog.on_cancelButton_clicked` receives all the arguments and can take action on that instance of `InfoDialog`. The problem is that as I connect the signals for my main window after I create it, `Gtk.builder` expects me to provide all the signal handlers in there, not just for the main window, but also for `InfoDialog` and its children - in general for every single signal defined in the UI .xml file.

What can I do to solve this, other than just calling `widget.connect()` manually for every child?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual way is to split the UI definitions for different windows/dialogs into separate XML files.

If you don't want to do that, you could use [`Gtk.Builder.connect_signals_full()`](http://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/index.html#Gtk-3.0/classes/Builder.html#Gtk.Builder.connect_signals_full), and pass a custom [function](http://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/index.html#Gtk-3.0/callbacks.html#Gtk.BuilderConnectFunc) that connects only the signals you want to connect.

Comment: Why didn't I think of that? It's the most obvious way... And thanks for telling me about the other function :)